# How to run separate threads multiple times in parallel in C#?

Tags: c#

Could I run this on multiple thread? I wanted to run each drive on separate thread but the code is the same. I am new to threads and background workers so please help me understand. Or maybe help me with some examples. Thanks you!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If conditions


        Scan(@"D:\"); // Sample Command to start on separate thread
        Scan(@"E:\"); // Sample Command to start on separate thread
        Scan(@"F:\"); // Sample Command to start on separate thread
    }

    private void Scan(String drive)
    {

        // I would like to start new thread on each drive
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir /b /s " + drive);
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem I think.

Comment: You don't need any threads. Just start all Processes and later wait until they exit.

Comment: @Clemens You have no idea how much I'm waiting for stable [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync?view=net-5.0) :)